# How to show foreground image and then hide on hover?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

How to show an image in the foreground and then upon a user hovering over that image the image would go away and the user can see what was behind it.

I tried combinations of `display: none` and `visibility: none`, but then the image wouldn't hover or not show completely

**view**

```
<div class="social-stuff">
  <div class="like-button">
    <%= link_to like_challenge_path(:id => @challenge.id), class: "btn", method: :post do %>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="text-background">
    <%= render "comments/comments" %>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.social-stuff {
  background: url('goal-setting.jpeg');
  &:hover {
   ??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/RuNpiXelruN/pen/jqRbpL) here for you. I've done it in two ways. Using CSS to change the image's opacity on hover and also using jQuery to animate the opacity of the image. Below is the code. It's setup to work using jQuery at the moment, but un-comment the css hover section out, and comment the jQuery, and the CSS version will work. Hope this helps.

### HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img id="image-foreground" src="https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/CA1U4gMJ2xG2s-tSfPTKJdiVFxw=/0x0:1687x1125/1280x854/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/48681987/titan-aerospace-drone-google.0.0.jpeg" alt="" />
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <p id="text-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam delectus, optio qui, magni suscipit error aperiam nemo veritatis quod sunt at perferendis accusantium quaerat. Repudiandae quaerat inventore voluptatum, sit eos.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.image-container {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 30vw;

  #image-foreground {
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;

    // &:hover {
    //   opacity: 0;
    // }
  }
  .text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    color: white;
    top: 15vh;
    left: 5vw;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
  }
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#image-foreground').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0
    },500, function(){
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
      },500)
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Very well done my friend. It works beautiful with image. I made some adjustments, but ran into a problem where I can't click on what is behind the hover. I explain more in this new question if you have time to dive in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217063/how-to-make-clickable-whats-behind-hover :)

Comment: Glad I could help @AnthonyGalli.com. I've just added an answer now to your other question. Hope that helps! Feel free to send me a message whenever you need :)