# How to make clickable what's behind hover?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hover

A user hovers over `glyphicon-globe` image and behind it lies a like button and a comment form. When a user goes to click on the button or the comment form nothing happens. How can I make clickable what lies behind the globe?

**view**

```
<div class="image-container">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" style="font-size: 7em; color: white; text-align: center; width: 100%; background-color: #446CB3; border-radius: 4px; padding: 19%;" id="image-foreground"></span>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <div class="like-button">
      <%= link_to like_challenge_path(:id => @challenge.id), class: "btn", method: :post do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="text-background">
      <%= render "comments/form" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;

  #image-foreground {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}

.text-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**no hover**

[image]

**hover**

[image]

Comment: due to `z-index` in `image-foreground` id you are not able to click that element

Comment: If it is only one element to be made clickable you could capture the click on the front object, make this object disappear and then generate a click in the element you need.

Comment: Thanks @pitabasprathal. Problem with that is I put z-index to negative in hover, but then the globe image is flashing in and out causing me to have a seizure

Comment: Please explain @EddeAlmeida in an answer. I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways I'd try. So you know, giving an element `opacity: 0;` won't make it disappear completely. It is still there in position but not able to be seen. To have an element removed also use both `opacity: 0;` and `visibility: hidden` in your `&:hover` action.

The second way you could do it is stick with `opacity: 0` but also set `z-index: 0` (or any number below the z-index of the underlying layers. You have the hover working nicely but because it has a higher `z-index` than the underlying layers, it is still technically sitting on top of them and covering them, making them unclickable.

Hope that helps

Also a side note to the answer below, one of the answers here suggested using `display: none` in your `hover` action. `display: none` doesn't work for this as once an element is set to `display: none`, it is no longer there, not part of the DOM and so breaks the hover action.

Comment: Hey did all the above. Still won't click :/ Thanks for the detailed explanation though :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do on hover display the blue screen as none.

```
.image-container:hover {
   display: none;
}
```

it that what you wanted ?

Comment: you could add to second one on hover display: block;

Comment: Nope to the latter. Same behavior as before, but I should elaborate on `display: none;` when I hover over it keeps flashing in and out. I can click, but the globe is acting erradicatly and won't stay gone if hovering on spot

Comment: You could do if you hover a variable called hover is set to True. Which then changes the background ?

Comment: Can you update answer with code? Not getting what you're putting out.

Comment: Something like if(hovering over image){ hide = true}; if (hide){document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";} sry if didnt work.

Comment: Nope, but thanks again. Same problem as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the trick that worked:

```
.hide-globe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccac00;
  padding: 100px;
}

.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute; // This was essential
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  &:hover { 
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white; // And this helped make the image seemingly go away
  }
}
```